# Sed: Convert to xml tag only if tag matches the first string

Tags: regex, xml, linux, unix, sed

I have a text file like this:

```
B1=text1
B2=text2
B3=text3
```

I have the following sed that will convert this text format to text between tags.

```
echo "String= Hello World" | sed 's#\([^=]\+\)=\(.*\)#<\1>\2</\1>#'
```

This sed gives this output:

```
<String > Hello World</String >
```

How to put the tag only if String beguns with B and a number, for example B45? so string will be B45

If String matches  B+number

Then Sed command to give this output (example)

```
<B1>text1</B1>
<B2>text2</B2>
<B3>text3</B3>
```

Comment: There are no spaces before the closing angle brackets!

Comment: [edit] your question to simply show a sample input file that includes both cases you do and don't want converted and the associated output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work for You :

```
echo "String= Hllo World" | sed 's#\([^=]\+\)=\(\s*B[0-9]*.*\)#<\1>\2</\1>#'
```

Comment: What happend here :
I added :
\s* - match as many whitespace as possible 
B - match letter B
[0-9]* - match as many numbers as possible 
I think it will do the job for You

Comment: but it removes the tags and the condition is still not applied.

Comment: What do You mean ? Your question was "How to put the tag only if String beguns with B and a number" So this is answer. Try giving more details so I will try help

Comment: Edited, check please.

Comment: so for this proupose sed command will look like this : 
sed 's#\(B[0-9]\+\)=\(.*\)#<\1>\2</\1>#'

Comment: Thanks , this was the solution
`echo "B56=Hello World | Tesfsqd f" | sed 's#\(B[0-9][^=]\+\)=\(.*\)#<\1>\2</\1>#'`

Answer (score 0):

Please don't use regular expression to manipulate XML. XML is a contextual language. Regex isn't, so it can NEVER work properly. At best, you have a dirty hack, that will one day break for no discernible reason, because it's making assumptions that aren't valid.

Please use a parser. It's not hard, but does mean you avoid creating brittle code.

Longhand in `perl`, it's:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $input = "String= Hello World";
my ($tag, $content) = split /=/, $input;

XML::Twig::Elt -> new ( $tag, $content ) -> print;
```

This outputs:

```
<String> Hello World</String>
```

As a more extensive example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $input = "";
my ( $tag, $content ) = split /=/, $input;

my $doc = XML::Twig->new( pretty_print => 'indented_a' ) ;
$doc->set_xml_version("1.0");
$doc->set_encoding('utf-8');
$doc->set_root( XML::Twig::Elt->new('root') );

while (<>) {
   chomp;
   my ( $tag, $content ) = split /=/;
   if ( $content =~ m/^B/ ) {
      $doc->root->insert_new_elt( 'last_child', $tag, $content );
   }
}

$doc->print;
```

Input of:

```
String= Hello World
tag=B1234 some text here
newtag=fish heads fish heads roly poly fish heads
String=Better fun joy here
```

Gives a result of:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <String>Better fun joy here</String>
  <tag>B1234 some text here</tag>
</root>
```

It's not too hard to use a proper parser, and if you need more reason to do so: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: Thank you for this script, if not possible regex with sed, I will look for awk.

Comment: `awk` also cannot manipulate XML safely, for the same reasons.